# Need to remove line breaks from a text file with certain conditions

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file running into 20,000 lines. A block of meaningful data for me would consist of name, address, city, state,zip, phone. My file has each of these on a new line, so a file would go like:

```
StoreName1
, Address
, City
,State
,Zip
, Phone

StoreName2
, Address
, City
,State
,Zip
, Phone
```

I need to create a CSV file and will need the above information for each store in 1 single line :

```
StoreName1, Address, City,State,Zip, Phone
StoreName2, Address, City,State,Zip, Phone
```

So essentially, I am trying to remove \r\n only at the appropriate points. How do I do this with python re. Examples would be very helpful, am a newbie at this.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be done with regex, and if so, is it homework?

Comment: Additionally - is the data "normal"?  Does every Store occupy 6 lines with a blank line separating, or is there expected variation (multiple address lines, phone numbers, etc)?

Comment: `perl -00 -i.bak -pe 's/\n,/,/g' whatever.txt` but feel free to call that using `python -c` if you really want to.   And you don’t have to worry about the carriage returns: `\n` will get a CRLF on a POB system. **See how *easy* that is? Use the right tool for the right task.** If your only tool is a hammer, then everything looks like a nail.  But it isn’t.

Comment: Actually, you're not "removing line breaks".  You're simply reformatting the file.  If you don't think of the line breaks specifically, but think of comma-separated fields that have newlines inside the fields.

Answer (score 3):

`s/[\r\n]+,/,/g`

Globally substitute 'linebreak(s),' with ','

Edit:
If you want to reduce it further with a single linebreak between records:

`s/[\r\n]+(,|[\r\n])/$1/g`

Globally substitute 'linebreaks(s) (comma or linebreak) with capture group 1.

Edit:
And, if it really gets out of whack, this might cure it:

`s/[\r\n]+\s*(,|[\r\n])\s*/$1/g`

Comment: You'd have to use `re.sub(r'[\r\n]+,', ',', mydata)` where `mydata` is the contents of the source file. Also, you still end up with extra line breaks after every 2nd line.

Answer (score 2):

This iterator/generator version doesn't require reading the entire file into memory at once

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("inputfile.txt") as f:
    groups = groupby(f, key=str.isspace)
    for row in ("".join(map(str.strip,x[1])) for x in groups if not x[0]):
        ...
```

Comment: @gnibbler IMO, I doubt that groups = groupby(f, key=str.isspace) can be executed and groups can be created without the file being read entirely

Comment: @eyquem, of course the entire file will be read as you iterate over all the rows. But _the entire file does not need to be in memory at once_. Each iteration of the for loop, just enough  of the file is read in to construct the row, and then this memory can be freed at once.

Comment: @gnibbler well, wait a minute, I study your solution . I need to examine groupby() functioning a little more

Comment: @eyquem, `str.isspace()` is called on each line. groupby groups consecutive values with the same key together, so the first group is the lines for Store1, the second group is the following blank lines (or line if there is always only one) since `"\n".isspace()` is True. The third group is the lines for Store2 and so on. You should open a question if you want a more detailed answer

Comment: @gnibbler No, thank you, I don't need to ask more, I've understood. That's an incredibly tricky solution ! I hadn't integrate in my mind the fact that the argument of groupby may be not only a sequence with elements already separated but also any iterator that will be processed as an iterator, that is to say by means of the process of an iteration (waooh!), to obtain the "chunks" produced by this iterator. So your solution is far more astute than the first mind-numbigly ones of mine. Did you see this solution somewhere or is it your own ? It is a solution "à la Martelli".

Comment: @gnibbler Consequently, you are right: the file is progressively read, it issn't needed to have the file entirely read in memory at once. Your solution should collect dozens of upvote.

Comment: @gnibbler You'll see my solution based on your lesson in my EDIT 3. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is "normal" - see my comment - I'd approach the problem this way:

```
with open('data.txt') as fhi, open('newdata.txt', 'w') as fho:
  # Iterate over the input file.
  for store in fhi:
    # Read in the rest of the pertinent data
    fields = [next(fhi).rstrip() for _ in range(5)]

    # Generate a list of all fields for this store.
    row = [store.rstrip()] + fields

    # Output to the new data file.
    fho.write('%s\n' % ''.join(row))

    # Consume a blank line in the input file.
    next(fhi)
```

Answer (score 0):

First mind-numbigly solution

```
import re

ch = ('StoreName1\r\n'
      ', Address\r\n'
      ', City\r\n'
      ',State\r\n'
      ',Zip\r\n'
      ', Phone\r\n'
      '\r\n'
      'StoreName2\r\n'
      ', Address\r\n'
      ', City\r\n'
      ',State\r\n'
      ',Zip\r\n'
      ', Phone')

regx = re.compile('(?:(?<=\r\n\r\n)|(?<=\A)|(?<=\A\r\n))'
                  '(.+?)\r\n(,.+?)\r\n(,.+?)\r\n(,.+?)\r\n(,.+?)\r\n(,[^\r\n]+)')

with open('csvoutput.txt','wb') as f:
    f.writelines(''.join(mat.groups())+'\r\n' for mat in regx.finditer(ch))
```

ch mimics the content of a file on a Windows platform (newlines == \r\n)

Second mind-numbigly solution

```
regx = re.compile('(?:(?<=\r\n\r\n)|(?<=\A)|(?<=\A\r\n))'
                  '.+?\r\n,.+?\r\n,.+?\r\n,.+?\r\n,.+?\r\n,[^\r\n]+')

with open('csvoutput.txt','wb') as f:
    f.writelines(mat.group().replace('\r\n','')+'\r\n' for mat in regx.finditer(ch))
```

Third mind-numbigly solution, if you want to create a CSV file with other delimiters than commas:

```
regx = re.compile('(?:(?<=\r\n\r\n)|(?<=\A)|(?<=\A\r\n))'
                  '(.+?)\r\n,(.+?)\r\n,(.+?)\r\n,(.+?)\r\n,(.+?)\r\n,([^\r\n]+)')
import csv

with open('csvtry3.txt','wb') as f:
    csvw = csv.writer(f,delimiter='#')
    for mat in regx.finditer(ch):
        csvw.writerow(mat.groups())
```

.

### EDIT 1

You are right , tchrist, the following solution is far simpler:

```
regx = re.compile('(?<!\r\n)\r\n')    
with open('csvtry.txt','wb') as f:
    f.write(regx.sub('',ch))
```

.

### EDIT 2

A regex isn't required:

```
with open('csvtry.txt','wb') as f:
    f.writelines(x.replace('\r\n','')+'\r\n' for x in ch.split('\r\n\r\n'))
```

.

### EDIT 3

Treating a file, no more **ch**:

'à la gnibbler" solution, in cases when the file can't be read all at once in memory because it is too big:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open('csvinput.txt','r') as f,open('csvoutput.txt','w') as g:
    groups = groupby(f,key= lambda v: not str.isspace(v))
    g.writelines(''.join(x).replace('\n','')+'\n' for k,x in groups if k)
```

I have another solution with regex:

```
import re
regx = re.compile('^((?:.+?\n)+?)(?=\n|\Z)',re.MULTILINE)
with open('input.txt','r') as f,open('csvoutput.txt','w') as g:
    g.writelines(mat.group().replace('\n','')+'\n' for mat in regx.finditer(f.read()))
```

I find it similar to the gnibbler-like solution

Comment: Holy Toledo!! That is like **mind-numbingly** complex compared with `perl -00 -pe 's/\n,/,/g'`! Why are you making it so hard?

Comment: @tchrist Hello. Because your perl expression is cabalistic for me: I don't know perl. I searched **mind-numbigly** in freedictionary.com', but it doesn't have this entry. What does it mean , please ?

Comment: @tchrist Can you explain the meaning of your perl expression ? Maybe, I don't see a simple principle of treatment that complexifies my solutions .

Comment: @eyquem Sure thing. `-00` sets the input record separator to 2+ adjacent linebreaks. `-p` means to loop around the input, reading a record at a time, and output whatever’s left of the record when the argument to `-e` has had its way with it. Looks like I should add a `-e '; s/\n{2,}$/\n/'` to avoid extra linebreaks. You can get perl to uncompile that for you so you can see the real code by running `perl -MO=Deparse -00 -i.bak -pe 's/\n,/,/g; s/\n{2,}$//'`. That should remove a lot of the mystery.

Comment: @eyquem: If you’re on a Prisoner of Bill system, then text files are by default processed in a way that maps CRLF to `\n` and back again, so you never have to worry about portability. This is an example of Perl masquerading as a special-purpose language instead of general-purpose one. It works like sed does in this regard, except you can’t do general programming in sed. :)

Comment: @tchrist Yes I am such a prisoner. But I above all took account of the demand of the OP who wrote _"I am trying to remove \r\n"_ I know that Python reads files with Universal Newline Support activated by default, that transforms the '\r\n' or '\r' of ancient MacIntosh in '\n' when reading a file not in binary mode

Comment: Oops, my mistake: it’s much easier than all that stuff.  Watch: `perl -lp00e 's/\n//g' <input >output` does the whole job. Isn’t that a lot easier than writing a program? Plus if you want to do it inplace with the original kept around as a backup, then `perl -i.bak -lp00e 's/\n//g' somefile` will do the updated-in-place trick, but YANETUT. 

Comment: If you have CRLF translation happening, why are the `\r`’s in your pattern? Won’t that break things?

Comment: @tchrist Ooooh... That's glossolalia for me

Comment: @tchrist I don't know why he speaks of '\r\n'. I answer to the questio as it is asked. I am a little tired to constantly asked for complementary information to persons who post questions. If they will have problems, they will react to the fact, instead of having foreseen it  (excuse my poor english)

Comment: @eyquem: I find that POBs often don’t think to turn to small tools for solutions the way any Unix user would automatically do. It is a really good idea.

Comment: @tchrist In Python, there is the function input() from module fileinput that processes treatments making backup if desired, and in place if specified

Comment: @eyquem: Yeah, we’ll prolly never see the OP again. Hit and run.

Comment: @tchrist You mean with command line ? Use of command line attracts me but until now , I have rarely used it. That's right that I always write programs, I have intention to study the possibilities of command line some day

Comment: @tchrist prolly, mind-dumbigly.... perl practitioners seem to be accustomed to use strange words...that I don't understand and don't find in dictionaries

Comment: @eyquem: The word is **mind-numbingly**.  Stem it down: *in a mind-numbing manner*.  Something that *numbs the mind*.  What is this “not in a dictionary” noise??

Comment: @tchrist oh, i didn't know the word 'numb' and didn't think  to search for it . Dictionary = my paper dictionary Larousse, and the on line freedictionary.com

Comment: @tchrist _"Use the right tool for the right task"_ I'll try to consider this advice more seriously henceforth

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open(infilepath, 'r')
s = ''.join([line for line in f])
s = s.replace('\n\n', '\\n')
s = s.replace('\n', '')
s = s.replace("\\n", "\n")
f.close()

f = open(infilepath, 'r')
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

That should do it. It will replace your input file with the new format

Comment: this won't work. Do you think "Phone" will "Phone" in every line????? It will be some value for phone!

Comment: -1 (1) Using `line.strip()` in the 2nd line of code will blow away all the `\n` characters in the file. Replace the 2nd line by `s = f.read()`. Or if you believe that the row-separator line may contain more whitespace than the terminating newline, change the 2nd code line to use `'\n'.join(....)`. (2) In any case, this "solution" will blow up if there's an instance of `\n` already in the data ... quite possible, careless data enterer hits `\` key instead of `Backspace` key.

Comment: @John Machin: Just changed the second line after considering what you said. What do you think now?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Your "fix" only addresses my first point, and only by a baroque equivalent of `s = f.read()`. Still -1.